# Issue with derivation of zeroth law of thermodynamics (from Kardar's statistical physics of particles)

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics

I'm going through the derivation of the zeroth law of thermodynamics on page 100 of Mehran Kardar's book titled "statistical physics of particles".

The derivation begins with the idea of bringing two microcanonical systems into contact with one another, and allowing them to exchange energy.

The composite system is now treated as a microcanonical ensemble, which is fine, but so are the two component systems, and that's where I'm having trouble.
How can we justify treating the component systems as microcanonical now that their energies are no longer fixed? I was under the impression that, by definition, the microcanonical ensemble describes a system with fixed total energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy is similar to the one used in thermodynamics: Compute the Energy in equilibrium, then break equilibrium and let the system evolve towards a new equilibrium situation. The energy is constant in the process since the whole system is isolated.

In more detail, when the experiment starts, both systems are separated and $E=E_1+E_2$ with both sub-systems in equilibrium separately. Therefore, both sub-systems have a microcanonical ensemble associated, with its own equilibrium temperature $T_1$ and $T_2$. Once they are put in contact, they are able to exchange energy and evolve towards a new equilibrium situation. However, since the interaction energy between both sub-systems is negligible, you can assume that the energy $E=E_1+E_2$ is constant through the entire process. Once the system is in equilibrium, the system has the same energy $E$ and one equilibrium temperature $T$.